# How to check if a specific integer value input from keyboard exist in a line or more lines of a file in C++

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, fstream

I have a small project for a C++ course and I'm stuck trying to check if a value of a data member of STUDENT's class exists in the file(the "ID"). I've tried to use some function that I found on the internet to transform the integer value I'm searching for into a string and then use the find function, to search for it in  each line of the file.

It works, but whenever I check one line from the file, it gets false pozitive, because the ID value(for example "12") is for example, identical to the value of age(also "12"). It does that because the age value comes before the ID value in my file and also in the string variable (and I can't change it). I don't know to search in the string for the value of ID only. I use the function "inputInfo" to input student1's member values from the keyboard, and function "checkID" to check if value of "ID" already exists in the file. Also, for another aspect of the project, I am seeking a way to search for occurrence of the ID and name data members values in the same file(once they are already written). One solution I've thought is to somehow start the search after the occurence of another character(for example the space character, given the fact that in the file, each field is delimited from another with a space), but I'm not sure the find function is able to do that.Thank you in advance for your help.Below is a part of the project's code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int checkID(int idNumber)
{
    string findID;
    stringstream id_string;
    id_string << idNumber;
    findID = id_string.str();
    int offset;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("Students.txt");
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while(getline(in, line))
        {
            if(offset = line.find(findID, 0)!= string::npos)
            {
                cout<<"The ID already exists. Insert a different ID!"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }
    else
        cout<<"File doesn't exist!"<<endl;
    in.close();
}

class PERSON
{
protected:
    string name;
    string surname;
    unsigned int age;
public:
    void inputinfo()
    {
        cin>>name;
        cin>>surname;
        cin>>age;
    }
    outputinfo()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
        cout<<surname<<endl;
        cout<<age<<endl;
    }
};

class STUDENT: public PERSON
{
    int ID;
    float marks_sum;
    string belonging_class;

public:

    inputInfo()
    {
        cout<<"Name:";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Surname:";
        cin>>surname;
        cout<<"Age:";
        cin>>age;
        do
        {
            cout<<"ID:";
            cin>>ID;
        }
        while (checkID(ID)==0);

        cout<<"Sum of marks:";
        cin>>marks_sum;
        cout<<"The belonging class:";
        cin>>belonging_class;

    }


    void outputInfo()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
        cout<<surname<<endl;
        cout<<age<<endl;
        cout<<ID<<endl;
        cout<<marks_sum<<endl;
        cout<<belonging_class<<endl;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const STUDENT& value )
    {
        os << value.name<<" "<<value.surname<<" "<<value.age<<" "<<value.ID<<" "<<value.marks_sum<<" "<<value.belonging_class<<std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

STUDENT student1;

int writeInFile(STUDENT studentx)
{
    ofstream os("Students.txt", ofstream::app);
    os << studentx;
    os.close();
}


int main()
{
    int opt1, opt2;
    char option;

    do
    {
        cout<<"1 -  Input data into file"<<endl<<"2 - Close program"<<endl;
        cin>>opt1;
        switch(opt1)
        {
        case 1:
            do
            {
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Choose one of variants"<<endl<<"1.Students"<<endl<<"2.Get back to main menu"<<endl;
                cin>>opt2;
                switch(opt2)
                {
                case 1:
                    do
                    {
                        cout<<"Do you wish to introduce a new student(Y/N)?";
                        cin>>option;
                        if(option!='N')
                        {
                            student1.inputInfo();
                            writeInFile(student1);
                        }
                    }
                    while (option!='N');
                    break;
                }

            }
            while(opt2!=2);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(opt1!=2);

}
```

Comment: Is your program stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: The actual code is not for sure. This is just a part of my code, and also translated in english, as my native language is not english.Why do you believe it's stuck in an infinte loop ?

Comment: Nvm I misread. But `checkID` doesn't return control along all path of recursion.

Comment: @lucieon, I found a solution to my problem, partialy. I remodeled my code and the content of my problem. I still can't figure out completely though, so any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool isUniqueID(ifstream& file, int id)
{

    string id_string = to_string(id);
    string currently_read_line;
    // The position of the searched key. So, in this case,
    // only the 3rd value will be tested (starting from 0).
    // John Doe 23 456
    //   |   |   |   |
    //   0   1   2   3 (the id)
    int offset = 3;

    while (getline(file, currently_read_line))
    {
        istringstream ss(currently_read_line);
        string current_entry;
        int counter = 0;

        while (ss >> current_entry) {

            if (current_entry == id_string && counter == offset) {
                cout << "The Id already exists." << endl;
                return false;
            }
            counter++;

        }
    }

    // No match found
    cout << "The ID does not exist yet." << endl;
    return true;

}
```

Please note:

- Just pass your opened file to the function. The file is opened once, instead of opening it every time you want to check an ID.
- This requires to compile in -std=c++11 (for the to_string conversion)

[Update]

The offset variable tells the function what value to test for. A more consistent way to do this, would be to format the data as to have a key/value for each student entry. It works as it though.

Comment: I have 3 questions regarding your solution: 1. is this function going to replace my checkID function in its entire form ?; 2. how do i modify my inputinfo so that i can pass the opened file as a function and to adjust to this new function?; 3. can you please help me by telling what do I need to add to my code so that I cand compile in c++11 (what header, or piece of code, because in my research, I've tried the to_string function, and it wasn't recognized by compiler. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even with this changes you've suggested, it still doesn't solve my problem (if age value is same with input ID, it checks with the age value, instead of ID value in the currently_read_line, simply because ID value is farther in the string, than the age value). For example, the  "currently_read_line " for one input in the file would look like this : "John Doe 45 2 9.50 XI". When I enter second students, with   4 as ID, it checks with 4 from "45", wich is the age of the first student, and not his ID. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I read too fast and missed the age part. Sorry for that. Then you need some data formatting! You need to change the way your data is saved in your file, so as you have a key for each entry of a student. No "simple" solution here. I will update the answer.

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for your answer. Right now each student's informations are saved on each line of the file. I found it easier this way, in order to check one line/one student. But as I soond discovered, it's giving me problems when ckecking certain info in that line....I'll wait for your update, thank you very much! :D

Comment: Updated. To compile, you need to add the -std=C++11 flag to your compiler. Depending on your IDE, it can be a matter of checking a box :). Yes, this function is meant to replace your checkID one. Finally, make your ifstream a member of your class, so you can access it from the inputinfo method (to call tisUniqueID).

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked as expected ( separated each string int each  line of file into independent strings and compared each and one of them with the ID input from keyboard). One last request, if it's not too much...can you show me in my current code the implementation of the ifstream as a member function of  of STUDENT's class and it's passing to the UniqueID ? I really don't know how to do it properly, since I'm fairly new to C++. Thank you in advance for all your help, Ireally apreciate it!

Comment: I meant attribute (a class variable). In your Person class, add another variable of 
 the type std::ifstream. Initialize it in its constructor (Person() method). You can then access it from any method of the parent and inherited classes, by calling this->nameYouGaveToYourFileStream. I encourage you to research the C++ class syntax. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will use your advice to make my code more efficient! Best of wishes !